# Happens-Before relation in Java Memory Model

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, java-memory-model, happens-before

Regarding JLS ch17 [Threads and Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html), it says "if one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second"; I wonder:

(1) What does it really mean by saying "ordered before"? Because even if action_a happens-before action_b, action_a can be executed after action_b in some implementation, right?

(2) If action_a happens-before action_b, does it mean action_a MUST NOT see action_b? Or action_a may see or may not see action_b?

(3) If action_a does NOT happen-before action_b, and action_b does NOT happen-before action_a, does it mean action_a may see or may not see action_b?

(4) There could not be any cyclic happens-before, right?

Any answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: The best explanation I ever read is Leslie Lamports original paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/time-clocks.pdf

Comment: @midor Great paper indeed; but here we're talking about Java Memory Model, not distributed system :-p

Comment: Yes, we do talk about Java, but the happened-before relation is something that spans pretty much all sections of CS where concurrent operation takes place. Afaik it is not redefined for Java, and I would be very surprised if it was so. Pretty much all of his questions are about the happened-before relation, so I would still consider Lamport's paper the best reference.

Comment: @midor If you look carefully at what is being asked, you'll see that OP does not seek clarification of what *happens-before* means, but rather how the specific rules of the JLS prevent unnatural outcomes such as circular causality.

Answer (score 6):

> (1) What does it really mean by saying "ordered before"? Because even if action_a happens-before action_b, action_a can be executed after action_b in some implementation, right?

*Happens-before* is a *causal*, not a *temporal* relationship. `action_a` is causally ordered before `action_b`, whether or not it actually executes before it. In practice, however, a runtime would have a really hard time maintaning the causality without temporal order. Check out [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761552/detailed-semantics-of-volatile-regarding-timeliness-of-visibility) which goes into some detail on the subject of causality.

> (2) If action_a happens-before action_b, does it mean action_a MUST NOT see action_b? Or action_a may see or may not see action_b?

There is a definite overall order of the visibility of actions to one other. This is dealt with by the section specifying *well-formed executions*. Therefore, for any two actions *a* and *b*, either *a* is visible to *b*, or *b* to *a*, or none of the above. A good read to understand the notion of well-formed executions is [Java Memory Model Examples: Good, Bad, and Ugly](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/request/jmmexamples.pdf).

> (3) If action_a does NOT happen-before action_b, and action_b does NOT happen-before action_a, does it mean action_a may see or may not see action_b?

Yes, either is possible. There is no guarantee either way.

> (4) There could not be any cyclic happens-before, right?

*Happens-before* must impose a partial ordering, and the key property of ordering is no loops.

Comment: For point-2. If action-a happens before action-b, then the changes done by action-a should be visible to action-b right?. Else, how does the *Happens before* relationship hold?

Comment: Of course, that's the definition of *happens-before*.

Comment: I got confused because you say -  *Therefore, for any two actions a and b, either a is visible to b, or b to a, or none of the above.* :)

Comment: Yes, I'm making a general statement about any two actions. Applied to our case it implies the answer to OP's question: "correct, action_a MUST NOT see action_b".

Comment: great points for (1)(3)(4); they really help; I'd appreciated that :) Regarding point-2, it's clear that if action_a happens-before action_b then action_a MUST be visible to action_b; however, I wonder, is there a guarantee that action_b MUST not be visible to action_a when action_a happens-before action_b? I could not find any explicit statement that says so; even in the _well-formed executions_ you mentioned, I could not find any.

Comment: Section 17.4.8, *Executions and Causality Requirements*, is all about the prevention of "out-of-thin-air" values, which could happen exactly if two actions were allowed to be visible to another.

Comment: A great read to understand the notion of well-formed executions is this one: [*Java Memory Model Examples: Good, Bad and Ugly*](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/request/jmmexamples.pdf).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for sharing this _Java Memory Model Examples_; I'm gonna dig into that. :)

Answer (score 2):

> What does it really mean by saying "ordered before"? Because even if
> action_a happens-before action_b, action_a can be executed after
> action_b in some implementation, right?

A *Happens before* relationship creates a memory barrier which prevents the execution of action-b before action-a. Thus *some* underlying JVM optimizations *cannot* be applied. So, **NO** action-a *cannot* be executed after or along with action-b.

> If action_a happens-before action_b, does it mean action_a MUST NOT
> see action_b? Or action_a may see or may not see action_b?

It means action-b *must see all the changes* brought about by action-a.

> If action_a does NOT happen-before action_b, and action_b does NOT
> happen-before action_a, does it mean action_a may see or may not see
> action_b?

*Happens-before* is a *transitive* relationship. So, if action-a happens before action-b which happens before action-c ... so on upto action-y, and action-y happens before action-z, then action-a happens before action-z.

A happens before relationship ensures that the *actions which follow* the current action, will see the changes made by the current action. If the changes are not seen, then a *happens before* doesn't exist.

> There could not be any cyclic happens-before, right?

Right, If action-a happens before action-b,action-c, action-d, then none among b,c,d can happen before action-a.

**Edit :**

The JLS says *It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.*. So, if action-a has a *happens before* relationship with action-b, then action-b can execute first provided the final is equivalent to the sate if action a had executed before action b. This is *implementation specific*. The JIT might decide to run action-b earlier than action a provided this *change in order* does not affect the *final* result.

2. Well, action-a is *independent* of action-b. atleast theoretically :)
3. *Happens before* specifies, *sequential* actions. If the actions are *parallel*, then a happens before doesn't exist.

Note : All this confusion is because of the *removal* of *happens before* by the the JIT if there is no dependency between two actions. Please read about [Escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But, for (1), please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439527/java-reordering-and-memory-model); for (2) what about action_b's impact on action_a? for (3) transitive is great, but what about "parallel" actions (no happens-before relations)?

Comment: @Kurtt.Lin - Check my edit. Also, check *Marko Toplonik's* answer. He is the one who taught me *Escape Analysis* :P

Comment: I wouldn't view any actions by the JITC as a "removal of *happens-before*" because it is a *conceptual* relationhsip whose semantic consequences must always be obeyed. Lock elision (I guess that's what you have in mind where you mention Escape Analysis) does not remove any *happens-before* relationships---the JITC just concludes that it can satisfy them without any memory barriers.