# Understanding memory consistency of BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

From the [`BlockingQueue` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections,
>   actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a BlockingQueue
>   happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that
>   element from the BlockingQueue in another thread.'

***QUESTION:*** What does it mean? What are the *actions prior to placing*? Are they ones that appear before `put()` invokation in the program code or what?

To provide some example, let's consider the following method that publishes objects into a shared `BlockingQueue`

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //Maybe it's not a good idea to sttore such Date in Person
    //but let's leave it that way
    private Date processingDate;
    //etc..
    //GET, SET, toString
}

public class MyClass{
    private final BlockingQueue<Person> personsToProceed = new LinkedBlockingQueue(1000);

    public void submitPerson(Person p){
         p.setProcessingDate(new Date());
         //Make some other changes on p
         personsToProceed.put(p);
    }

    public void processPerson(){
        Person p = personsToProceed.take();
        //persist it into a DB
    }
}
```

Judging by the [`LinkedBlockingQueue.put()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29) implementation I would not say that `p.setProcessingDate(new Date());` and `personsToProceed.take();` keep happens-before order. Actually (comments ommited):

```
public void  put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
        if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        int c = -1;
        final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        putLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            try {
                while (count.get() == capacity)
                    notFull.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                notFull.signal(); // propagate to a non-interrupted thread
                throw ie;
            }
            insert(e);
            c = count.getAndIncrement();
            if (c + 1 < capacity)
                notFull.signal();
        } finally {
            putLock.unlock();
        }
        if (c == 0)
           signalNotEmpty();
  }
```

All we can say is that `put(p)` and `take()` are in happens-before. But since `p.setProcessingDate(new Date());` and `put(p)` are not, than `take()` in the `processPerson()` method is ***racy*** with `p.setProcessingDate(new Date());`

What did I miss?

Comment: "Are they ones that appear before put() invokation in the program code" Yes.

Comment: The memory barrier provided by `put()` (or rather `lockInterruptibly()`) ensures that `take()` cannot retrieve a `Person` whose processingDate isn't set. I don't see anything *racy* in that method.

Comment: @Kayaman Is it possible for compiler to move `p.setProcessingDate(new Date());` after the synchronization barrier of `put()`?

Comment: No. The memory barrier guarantees that the `happens-before` is fulfilled, so as you asked in your question, all the operations before `put()` are done by that time.

Comment: @St.Antario: Not barring compiler bugs, at least. That is indeed what the documentation's guarantee is saying.

Comment: @Kayaman Of course it cannot. _If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)._ Got it...

Comment: In Java 5 the Java Memory Model was fixed/improved due to some bugs in earlier versions. I can't remember any problems with the memory model after that.

Comment: Do you understand [what _happens before_ means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636829/happens-before-relation-in-java-memory-model)?

Comment: @Raedwald I didn't understand it correctly. But now yes, I think I do...